# How can I make python 2.6 my default in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

I just upgraded to lion and with it came Python 2.7.  I need to use 2.6 as my default python as the project I primarily work on uses 2.6.

Comment: have u think about using virtualenv?!

Comment: Maybe something here will work? http://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Apple has provided two very simple ways to change the default python on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and 10.7 Lion.  It's all detailed in the Apple man page for python(1):

```
$ man python
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -V
Python 2.7.1
#
# temporarily change version
#
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.6
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
$ unset VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION
$ python -V
Python 2.7.1
#
# persistently change version
#
$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, OP should change his selected solution.

Comment: Note you need to use the defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6 if you are installing and require Python 2.6. Otherwise the python package will be put into 2.7 site packages.

Comment: @Timbo: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I tried this on a computer with OS X 10.7.5. The string VERSIONER does not appear in the output from `man 1 python`. If I try the steps in the answer, I get 2.4.3. Should we update the answer?

Comment: It's still valid as of OS X 10.9.1.  Are you sure that the man page you were looking at wasn't from a third-party installation of Python, not the Apple-supplied one?  Try `man --path python`.  It should be 
`/usr/share/man/man1/python.1`

Comment: Interesting.  This computer's `man --path python` output is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/man/man1/python.1` Surely that's Apple's?  However, there is a `/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz`.  And that file (un-gzip'd) does mention VERSIONER.  I checked and indeed MacPorts is present.  Ports  python27 and python_select are active, so perhaps it messed up the `man` search path.

Comment: No, `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` is the location of  the Apple-supplied system Pythons in OS X.  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` is where third-party frameworks like the python.org ones are installed.  MacPorts Pythons are installed elsewhere, by default, `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

Answer (score 4):

After running the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
```

To make sure the packages you install with 'sudo' are installed for the correct Python version, also set the versioner option as a superuser:

```
sudo su
# Enter password
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. <strike>Change /usr/bin/python to a link to /usr/bin/python2.6</strike>
2. Put /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin in your path before /usr/bin
3. Explicitly tell your scripts to use /usr/bin/python2.6

Comment: Do not use option 1 for the reasons cited in the other answer.  It's not a symlink on OS X.

Comment: 2 and 3 will work and are non-destructive but, as noted in another answer, Apple provides a much easier way to do this.