# Python being auto-aliased in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation

I have been struggling with setting Python 2.7 to be the default Python on my system.

Python 2.6 came with my OS, and I have since installed 2.7 (from source) and have been trying to make that my default version.

At one point it was suggested that I try a package manager (MacPorts / Fink / Homebrew) and I did, and I think that may have been a bad idea.

The overall issue is that, somewhere, somehow, Python 2.6 is getting auto-aliased as my default python every time my shell starts.  I've gone through my .profile and .bashrc, and there are no commands that could alias them.

I've also set my default path to look at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` first.  I have also tried the suggestions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998545/how-can-i-make-python-2-6-my-default-in-mac-os-x-lion) and this [SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/304220/how-can-i-update-the-default-python-installation-fix-my-path-on-mac-os-x-10-6-7) to no avail.  I need to use 2.7 as my default, because I have scripts that depend on argparse and so on.

Further, my /usr/bin/python is not aliased to anything, and /usr/local/bin is: `/usr/local/bin/python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Comment: As a side note: Have you considered using `virtualenv`? You can set up however many virtual environments you want, around whichever Python installations (Apple or otherwise) you want, and explicitly pick the one you want to activate at any time.

Comment: I am seriously starting to consider it.

Comment: `virtualenv` really is cool. There's a reason it was added to the standard library in 3.3. Once you're in a situation where you have to pay attention to your environment (and really, once you're not just using your system's default Python 2.x, especially if you're installing another copy of the same 2.x version you already had, you are), you might as well make it explicit and easy to do so.

Comment: Anyway, the key pieces of information we need are: Is there actually an `alias` for `python` (as shown by the `alias` command)? If so, what is it? What does `which python` show? If it's Apple's `/usr/bin/python` wrapper, or anything else besides what you expected, what's does `echo $PATH` show? If it's the wrapper, what do `echo $VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` and `defaults read com.apple.versioner.python` show? Finally, `ls -l` (or `readlink`) every relevant binary.

Comment: One last side question: Is it conceivably plausible that you could move to Python 3? If you install, say, 3.3, you'll generally run your 2.6 with `python` and your 3.3 with `python3`, so it's almost impossible to get those mixed up. And almost all of the other problems that come with having two 2.7s don't apply when you have a 2.7 and a 3.3.

Comment: Sadly no, everything I use requires < 3

Comment: Are you sure? Most people who say that, when I ask what they need, and it's `numpy` or `BeautifulSoup` or something else that has worked in 3.x for a long time now, or it's some tiny third-party library that can be ported by just running `2to3` on it…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have been struggling with setting Python 2.7 to be the default Python on my system.

It already was. When you take a clear Lion box, and type `python` into a shell, it runs `/usr/bin/python`, which is Python 2.7.2.

> Python 2.6 came with my OS

Lion comes with 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7, and a hidden 2.3.

They're installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`. All but 2.3 have symlinks `/usr/bin/python2.x` that, on a clean system, will be the first thing on your PATH with that name, so just typing `python2.6` will run 2.6, while `python2.7` will run 2.7.

And there's also a special wrapper at `/usr/bin/python` that runs 2.7 by default, but you can configure that with `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` or the `com.apple.versioner.python` preference.

> I have since installed 2.7 (from source) and have been trying to make that my default version.

What do you mean by "default version"? Do you just want it to be what gets run when you type `python` in a fresh Terminal shell, or use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as a shebang line in a script?

The easiest way to do that is to get whatever directory you installed it into higher on the PATH than /usr/bin.

If you've installed a "framework build" (which you should have), there will be a directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` that you can put at the top of your PATH. This avoids affecting the order of /usr/local and /usr, and it means you can use any scripts that get installed by Python setup.py installations without having to symlink them into /usr/local/bin.

This is important, because Apple's Python will install scripts into /usr/local/bin—for example, if you `/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip`, you'll get `/usr/local/bin/pip` and /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7`. If you also install`pip` for your custom-built Python, you don't want it to appear in the same place; otherwise, whichever you installed last replaces the other.

If you didn't install a framework build, or you've configured it to install scripts to `/usr/local/bin` anyway, or you *want* to affect the order of /usr/local, just put `/usr/local/bin` at the top of your PATH.

> somehow, Python 2.6 is getting auto-aliased as my default python every time my shell starts

By auto-aliased, you mean there's a bash `alias`? As in you type `alias` and it gives you a list of things including `python`?

If so, you need to fix this, not try to pile another hack on top of it to undo whatever effect it has.

If there's no alias commands in `~/.*`, look in `/etc/`. If you `grep -r alias /etc`, it will give you a big list of things, and you'll have to skip over the mail aliases and apache aliases (and possibly some permission denied output to stderr), but after that, there should be no shell aliases.

> Further, my /usr/bin/python is not aliased to anything,

This makes me think you're confusing aliasing and symlinking. They're not the same thing. Which one is the problem? You have to know what's wrong before you can fix it.

So, try this:

```
which python
```

It should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` if your PATH is what you say it is. If not, you're not setting up your PATH right, so `echo $PATH` and see.

If if *is* that, then `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. It should be a symlink to `python2.7` or `./python2.7`, not to anything in some other directory. If not, your installation is broken, and the best thing to do is uninstall Python and reinstall it properly. Or just *don't* reinstall it, and use Apple's. Or, if you actually need 2.7.3 instead of 2.7.2, or you need to build standalone `py2app` bundles (especially if you need them to be compatible with older OS X), or you're allergic to `sudo` and prefer having system-wide files being world-writable, or for some other reason you can't use Apple's, install from python.org or Homebrew instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: Actually, your comment about looking for an alias in /etc worked...there was a /etc/profile that was automatically adding the 2.6 alias.  Once that was removed everything started falling back into place...thanks!

Comment: You may want to find out where that alias came from, because… that's a very odd thing to happen behind your back, and if some installer you ran or something did that, it may have done all kinds of other bad things…