# How many versions of python are pre-installed on OS X?

Tags: python, macos

According to the documentation, the Apple-provided build of Python is installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and `/usr/bin/python`, respectively. Does this mean there are two copies of python installed?

In `/usr/bin/`, I have `python`, `python2.5`, `python2.6`, and `python2.7`. While `python2.5`, `python2.6`, and `python2.7`, are links to their respective versions in `/System/Library/Frameworks/`, it seems that `python` is not a link and is the executable itself.

My output of `ls-l` in `usr/bin/python` is:

`-rwxr-xr-x   2 root   wheel     58608 Mar  7 00:24 python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        75 Mar  7 00:24 python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        75 Mar  7 00:24 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        75 Mar  7 00:24 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern OS X systems, `/usr/bin/python` is a special "wrapper" executable provided by Apple to allow management of which version of Python and which CPU architecture (e.g. 32-bit or 64-bit) is executed by `/usr/bin/python`.  There are more details in [a previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998545/how-can-i-make-python-2-6-my-default-in-mac-os-x-lion/7000324#7000324) and in Apple's `python` man page (`man 1 python`).  As you noticed, the versioned Python files (`/usr/bin/python2.7` et al) are symlinks to the universal Python executables in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

This is another reason, by the way, why you should not attempt to modify files in `/usr` (other than `/usr/local`) or in `/System/Library`; they are not always what you think they are.  Files in those locations are part of OS X and are managed by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `/usr/bin/python -V` to see what the version of that python is. That binary contains the python interpreter.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` should contains the python system libraries that you import. You can verify this by starting the python in the shell (the following is output from a Linux box):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 15:40:47) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

Comment: And what about `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`? It has the same version as `/usr/bin/python`, but none of them are symlinks.

Comment: The symlinks in `/usr/bin` are pointing to the binary in that location. Unless I'm not understanding your question?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is not a symlink. That's why the question still stands, "Does this mean there are two copies of python installed?".

Comment: Yes there are at least 3 copies (Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7). He needs to do a `/usr/bin/python -V` to see if the fourth is a redundant version or not.

Comment: I mean `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python` are both executables (not symlinks) and both have the version `2.7.5`.

Comment: Yes then those two appear to be duplicates. You can further verify this by running `openssl sha1 /path/to/binary` on both and seeing if they have the same value. More reading here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1652

Comment: No, `/usr/bin/python` on OS X systems is not a duplicate.  See my answer for more details.