# Xcode 9.1 export fails with "The /usr/bin/xattr tool may be damaged"

Tags: xcode9.1

Xcode 9.0.1 crash when export ipa or upload to App Store in MacOS 10.13.1.

After upgraded to Xcode 9.1 (9B55), it shows error as below when export.

```
Stripping extended attributes failed.
"/usr/bin/xattr -crs /var/folders/mm/h01jykrs7gv9w7jjb0yt609w0000gp/T/XcodeDistPipeline.Uay/Root/Payload/GitSmartHome.app" exited with a non-zero status. The /usr/bin/xattr tool may be damaged.
```

It seems xattr was damaged, and when run xattr in Terminal, it prompts below error.

```
xattr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3019, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 655, in _build_master
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in require
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'xattr==0.6.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How to fix it or re-install xattr?

Comment: My error was similar, but it was due to permissions issues. So `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Library/Python/` resolved this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode always looks at `/usr/bin/xattr`, regardless of your paths (as you might have a working xattr installed elsewhere).

Typing in `/usr/bin/xattr` gave this output:

```
/usr/bin/xattr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xattr-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

You need to get your system's python happy again. I seem to have broken mine at some point. Not sure how.

I ran the following and got a screen full of errors.

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install -U setuptools
```

Afterwards, I ran `/usr/bin/xattr` again it it was silent. This seems to be the test for whether it's healthy.

My XCode exports now without the error.

The crux is that your /usr/bin/xattr will give you some kind of error, whether it's permissions or some other python/setup issue. You need to fix that to have your builds working again.

Edit:
For those with permission issues, run this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Users/$USER/Library/Python
```

Comment: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -U setuptools                  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py'               /usr/bin/xattr      same error

Comment: See my edit. You have the permission issue:  `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -g) /Users/$USER/Library/Python`

Comment: 'sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install -U setuptools' 'Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages' '/usr/bin/xattr''pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'xattr==0.6.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application'

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. It turned out that this started happening after I zapped `/Library/Python/2.7` and with it I deleted `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth`. Here's what was in it:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

The first of these directories contains an old version of xattr that still supports `-c` option (something I could not resolve by installing xattr v0.6.4 myself).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the issue was fixed via re-install MacOS, including Apple default Python.

Comment: That definitely saved my life! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

➜  /usr/bin/xattr
python version 2.7.14 can't run /usr/bin/xattr.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/xattr-2.6 (uses python 2.6)
/usr/bin/xattr-2.7 (uses python 2.7)

Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
➜  cd /usr/bin
➜  sudo rm xattr
➜  sudo ln -s xattr-2.7 xattr
➜  /usr/bin/xattr

Comment: This worked for me but had to boot to recovery mode (CMD+R), open a terminal and csrutil disable, reboot before I could create a link, then repeat and csrutil enable to reenable SIP.

Answer (score 0):

@Ren gave a good hint, following his thought, with the help of [Ned Deli's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998545/how-can-i-make-python-2-6-my-default-in-mac-os-x-lion), solved the problem here.

My situation: python 2.7 as default system version(use pyenv normally). /usr/bin/xattr always tempts to call /usr/bin/xattr-2.7, which won't be successful. Calling `xattr-2.6` works fine, forcing /usr/bin/xattr call xattr-2.6 leads to "option -c not recognized" while the XCode trying to call `xattr -crs ....`

Solution: After using command: `$defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6` Xcode can finally distribute my app.

You can set your system default python whenever you like back to 2.7 with:
`$unset VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the issue was fixed via re-install MacOS, including Apple default Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your mac throws you an error like "option -c not recognized" you can still try to launch the original source code "xattr python tool" using a command like this:

```
sudo python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/xattr/tool.pyc -cr /Applications/[Application].app
```

It works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and resolved it with:

`/usr/bin/python -m pip install xattr==0.6.4`

Answer (score -1):

reinstall xcode-select, open terminal and type

`xcode-select --install`